# Imagick extension don't works

Tags: php, imagick, pecl

Hi everyone this is my first post here and i need help to solve an error so let me explain it, i'm using PHP 8.2 and i want to use imagick extensión, so i downloaded the .dll file and i moved to the ext directory and i added too this line to my php.ini "extension=imagick" but when i use phpinfo() the extension doesn't appaers and i already checked the log file of apache server it contains the next line "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick' (tried: ext\imagick (No se puede encontrar el m\xc3\xb3dulo especificado), ext\php_imagick.dll (No se puede encontrar el m\xc3\xb3dulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0.

So, anybody knows what's happening? i already activated another extensions with the defaults settings in php.ini file and i have never obtained that error.

I dont know what i should to do because all mi settings in php.ini file are right.

Comment: The error says (in Spanish, thanks Google Translate) That is can't find the module. So either it's in the wrong file name, wrong location or it's an incorrect DLL file.